# If the value of pandas series is a list, how to get a subList of each element?

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, series

Using two Pandas series: *series1*, and *series2*, I am willing to make *series3*.
Each value of *series1* is a list, and each value of *series2* is a corresponding index of series1.

```
>>> print(series1)

0      [481, 12, 11, 220, 24, 24, 645, 153, 15, 13, 6...
1      [64, 80, 79, 147, 14, 20, 56, 288, 12, 208, 26...
4      [5, 6, 152, 31, 295, 127, 711, 5, 271, 291, 11...
5          [363, 121, 727, 249, 483, 122, 241, 494, 555]
7      [112, 20, 41, 9, 104, 131, 26, 298, 65, 214, 1...
9      [129, 797, 19, 151, 448, 47, 19, 106, 299, 144...
11     [72, 35, 25, 200, 122, 5, 75, 30, 208, 24, 14,...
18     [137, 339, 71, 14, 19, 54, 61, 15, 73, 104, 43...



>>> print(series2)

0       0
1       3
4       1
5       6
7       4
9       5
11      7
18      2
```

What I expect:

```
>>> print(series3)

0      [481, 12, 11, 220, 24, 24, 645, 153, 15, 13, 6...
1      [147, 14, 20, 56, 288, 12, 208, 26...
4      [6, 152, 31, 295, 127, 711, 5, 271, 291, 11...
5      [241, 494, 555]
7      [104, 131, 26, 298, 65, 214, 1...
9      [47, 19, 106, 299, 144...
11     [30, 208, 24, 14,...
18     [71, 14, 19, 54, 61, 15, 73, 104, 43...
```

**My solution 1**:
From the fact that the length of *series1* and *series2* are equal, I could make a for loop to iterate *series1* and calculate something like `series1.ix[i][series2.ix[i]]` and make a new series(*series3*) to save the result.

**My solution 2**:
Generate a dataFrame df using `df = pd_concat([series1, series2])`, and make a new column(row-wise operation using apply function - e.g., df['series3'] = df.apply(lambda x: subList(x), axis=1).

However, I thought above two solutions are not sharp ways to achieve what I want. I would appreciate if you suggest neater solutions!

Comment: What other kinds of solutions were you hoping for? Essentially, you are going to have to loop over your rows. `pandas` wasn't designed with having `list`s as values in mind, so there won't be any built-in functions to accomodate things like vectorized list-slicing. The "neatest" solution I could come up with is `pd.concat([S1, S2], axis=1).apply(lambda x: x[0][x[1]:], axis=1)` (assuming the "columns" will be simple integer labels) but this is no more efficient than the simple for-loop you mention.

Comment: Indeed, look how much easier it is to just work with plain Python lists: `L1, L2 = S1.tolist(), S2.tolist()` then simply `list(map(lambda x,y : x[y:], L1, L2))` and it's probably as efficient (more really) than the `pandas` operations.

Comment: 1. I didn't want to make a copied dataFrame to perform that calculation. I hope somebody knows the better answer than that. 

2. It's a bit dangerous to convert Series to List in my case. A miscalculation could be done if ignore indices.

Comment: If you want to be memory efficient, you will have to write a for-loop. Again, `pandas` and the underlying `numpy` are not meant to really be used with `list`s as values.

Comment: Then, which data structures would be better to deal multiple lists? Since I am doing feature engineering(data mining), I have been using pandas dataFrame to save features.

Comment: A list of lists? A dictionary of lists? That is basically what a `Series` of lists is. If it is working for you anyway, no need to change it. I just want to be clear, don't expect the efficiency/speed gains of `pandas`/`numpy`, so don't shy away from for-loops, because there is no reason to avoid them now! But if it is easier to work with `pandas` anyway, go for it!

Comment: Thanks for your comment @juanpa.arrivillaga. I think I will continue using `pandas` before I get used to alternatives. I'll accept your answer soon(the one using map function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are hoping to avoid creating an intermediate `pd.DataFrame`, and simply want a new `pd.Series`, you can use the `pd.Series` constructor on a `map` object. So given:

```
In [6]: S1
Out[6]:
0    [481, 12, 11, 220, 24, 24, 645, 153, 15, 13, 6]
1    [64, 80, 79, 147, 14, 20, 56, 288, 12, 208, 26]
2    [5, 6, 152, 31, 295, 127, 711, 5, 271, 291, 11]
3      [363, 121, 727, 249, 483, 122, 241, 494, 555]
4    [112, 20, 41, 9, 104, 131, 26, 298, 65, 214, 1]
5    [129, 797, 19, 151, 448, 47, 19, 106, 299, 144]
6     [72, 35, 25, 200, 122, 5, 75, 30, 208, 24, 14]
7    [137, 339, 71, 14, 19, 54, 61, 15, 73, 104, 43]
dtype: object

In [7]: S2
Out[7]:
0    0
1    3
2    1
3    6
4    4
5    5
6    7
7    2
dtype: int64
```

You can do:

```
In [8]: pd.Series(map(lambda x,y : x[y:], S1, S2), index=S1.index)
Out[8]:
0    [481, 12, 11, 220, 24, 24, 645, 153, 15, 13, 6]
1                [147, 14, 20, 56, 288, 12, 208, 26]
2       [6, 152, 31, 295, 127, 711, 5, 271, 291, 11]
3                                    [241, 494, 555]
4                    [104, 131, 26, 298, 65, 214, 1]
5                            [47, 19, 106, 299, 144]
6                                  [30, 208, 24, 14]
7              [71, 14, 19, 54, 61, 15, 73, 104, 43]
dtype: object
```

If you want to *modify `S1`* without creating an intermediate container, you can use a for-loop:

```
In [10]: for i, x in enumerate(map(lambda x,y : x[y:], S1, S2)):
    ...:     S1.iloc[i] = x
    ...:

In [11]: S1
Out[11]:
0    [481, 12, 11, 220, 24, 24, 645, 153, 15, 13, 6]
1                [147, 14, 20, 56, 288, 12, 208, 26]
2       [6, 152, 31, 295, 127, 711, 5, 271, 291, 11]
3                                    [241, 494, 555]
4                    [104, 131, 26, 298, 65, 214, 1]
5                            [47, 19, 106, 299, 144]
6                                  [30, 208, 24, 14]
7              [71, 14, 19, 54, 61, 15, 73, 104, 43]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can basically concatinate series specifiying wich axis(0=row,1 column),better be of the same lenght

```
series3=pd.concat([series2, series1], axis=1).reset_index()
```